# c# Nhibernate Session Not updating

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session

I am noticing a weird behavior in my application which is using NHibernate

To give you a bit of background, there are 2 tables in the database:

1) Transaction
2) Vehicle

A transaction has one to one association with vehicle.

I have a database helper class which has Save and GetAll methods in it.

So when i run the following code, everything works as intended.

```
Transaction t;

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    t = dbHelper.GetAll<Transaction>(session)[0];

    t.Vehicle.Odometer = "777";

    dbHelper.Save(t, session);  // This updates the vehicle table's odometer property to 777    
}
```

However, if i modify my code as follows

```
Transaction t;

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    t = dbHelper.GetAll<Transaction>(session)[0];
}

using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    t.Vehicle.Odometer = "777";

    dbHelper.Save(t, session);  // This does not update the vehicle table.

    // but

    dbHelper.Save(t.Vehicle, session); // Works  
}
```

So does that mean that the relationship properties are session dependent ?

**edit:**

I am using Fluent with AutoMapper and this is one of the convention classed i am using:

```
internal class OneToOneConvention : IHasOneConvention 
{ 
   public void Apply(IOneToOneInstance instance) 
   { 
     instance.Cascade.All(); 
   } 
}
```

**edit**

Here are the 2 methods inside dbHelper

```
  public void Save<T>(T entity, ISession session) 
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

and GetAll

```
public IList<T> GetAll<T>(ISession session) where T : class
        {
                return session.CreateCriteria<T>().List<T>();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show us your mappings, i would suspect that you don't have Cascade on your mapping.

Comment: I'm deeply suspicious of dbHelper - can you illuminate us? Also: having a bespoke Transaction class in the middle of a bunch of DB session related processes may not be the best naming scheme for the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong way. When you are retreiving `Transaction` object you should make changes inside this NH `Session`. Instead of using session that is disposed after `using` block, and then you are creating new one. If you need to decouple some logic after you get object from some `Session`, then you should pass your `Session` instead of creating new one. So workflow in your case should be as follow:

1. Open session and retreive `Transaction` object
2. Make CRUD operations on object (with NHibernate transaction)
3. Commit or Rolback transaction
4. Close session

Answer (score 0):

The relationship from Transaction to Vehicle is many-to-one not one-to-one. How do you have this mapped?

I agree that this (dbHelper) is not a good pattern for working with NHibernate.